# RAID 1 on Boot Disk Recovery

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I am using software RAID 1 under Linux on a bootable partition. I am worried that when a disk dies or is corrupted, the system might boot from the empty replacement disk or from that corrupted disk (instead of the good one) and start overwriting the good disk with no or bad data. Is this a valid concern? If so, does anyone have a good strategy for preventing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

into raid one you don't access the drives directly
but trough a second layer so you should not be worry
FYI http://www.howtoforge.com/software-raid1-grub-boot-debian-etch
describes as well the way to install grub which is 
the boot loader.

Comment: This answer doesn't really allay my concerns. What if the higher layer gets confused? Is that likely? How would it know which copy of the data is not corrupted? Maybe that empty disk is the result of a legitimate deletion and that disk full of data should be deleted.

Comment: if you install the grub into both disks you should be fine - see the tutorial on how to do it. even if one disk is bad you can still boot from the other one but the key is to have grub installed.